# Comparison between str and int fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

thats the general idea of what i'm doing but i end up with this

```
print("How old are you?")
age = sys.stdin.readline()

time.sleep(2) #delay for 2 seconds

if age> 15: #if the age entered it oer 15 then
    print("Welcome to Narnia, please follow me.")

else :
    print("Please go home.")
```

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Please use `age=input("How old are you? ")` instead of your first two lines.

Comment: Conversion to int is missing. And do use the correct Python version tag next time

Comment: you mean `age = int(input(...))`. Convert to int or it won't work as expected in python 3.

Comment: whats the correct python tag? im sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @JasonLian You're on Python 3. Ints and strings are orderable in Python 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert the age to an integer
use

```
age = int(sys.stdin.readline())
```

that way the line you read from the input will be saved as an integer and will be of the right type to be compared to the integer 15